# Graphics are rendered outside the form with GDI+

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I am currently making a game with GDI+, I know it is not the optimal solution for developing a game, but since it is a school project I have no choice.

About every tenth time I run my game, the graphics gets rendered outside the form in the top left corner of the screen.

I'm using double buffering if that helps to narrow the problem down.

The rendering code looks like this:

```
while (true)
{       
    // Create buffer if it don't exist already
    if (context == null)
    {
        context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
        this.buffer = context.Allocate(CreateGraphics(), this.DisplayRectangle);
    }

    // Clear the screen with the forms back color
    this.buffer.Graphics.Clear(this.BackColor);

    // Stuff is written to the buffer here, example of drawing a game object:
    this.buffer.Graphics.DrawImage(
        image: SpriteSheet,
        destRect: new Rectangle(
            this.Position.X
            this.Position.Y
            this.SpriteSheetSource.Width,
            this.SpriteSheetSource.Height),
        srcX: this.SpriteSheetSource.X,
        srcY: this.SpriteSheetSource.Y,
        srcWidth: this.SpriteSheetSource.Width,
        srcHeight: this.SpriteSheetSource.Height,
        srcUnit: GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // Transfer buffer to display - aka back/front buffer swapping 
    this.buffer.Render();
}
```

It's easier to explain with a screenshot:

[image: Game gfx outside win form problem]

Comment: Is that being rendered directly onto the form or a control?

Comment: What's `BufferedGraphicsManager` look like?

Comment: It is being rendered diectley to the form, the code is placed inside the class derived from the Form base class.

Comment: @Austin I'm not quite sure, it's a part of the System.Drawing.dll

Comment: Above comment was for @minitech not Austion ;-)

Comment: Sounds like you are rendering to the Windows Desktop context (DC) sometimes (if you were using the WinAPI directly the window handle would be 0 for the desktop).
Are you waiting for the form to be created before starting the game loop?

Not sure why you are creating your context/buffer inside the game draw loop. Is there any reason why it would be null any time after creation?

    this.buffer.Render();
What happens inside this call?

Comment: @DanStory I think you got it! I started the render loop on a seperate thread in the forms constructor, so the form might not have been fully created. I tried starting the thread for the render loop on the forms load event, and I don't seam to get the bug anymore! However I'm only 90% sure, as it's a relatively rare bug, it only occurs sometimes, but I haven't got it so far after the changes. I guess there's no reason to create the buffer inside the loop, will fix that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lange That's the great thing about bugs that deal with threads, it doesn't always happen every time. The timing has to just be right, sometimes it can take longer or shorter amount of time to create the thread and start executing. The quicker for the thread to start up, the more likely the form has not been created yet, which would return a window handle of IntPtr.Zero (and not checking for that the GDI is just gonna think you're trying to draw on the desktop context). But either cause, hope all that was.

Comment: @DanStory - please answer the question so you get your points and the question is not left unanswered.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was your own class :P I always just override `OnPaint`. Looks like Hans Passant already addressed that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> About every tenth time I run my game, the graphics gets rendered
>   outside the form in the top left corner of the screen.

From the screen shot and your description, you are occasionally drawing to the Window's Desktop device context (DC); Which is the effect of using a window handle of zero (IntPtr.Zero) when getting the DC.
This lead me to believe you could be starting the game loop before the form window has been created resulting in the graphics context to point to a zero'd window handle.

As confirmed in the commentary you are using a separate thread for your game loop resulting in the random behavior of this happening. Once dealing with threads, you don't always get the same result twice when it comes to timing of start up and completion of threads (especially when threads can run parallel, via a multi-core/cpu computer). Each time the game application is ran, there is a chance the game loop thread can start-up and execute before the form window on the UI thread can be created and shown.

Answer (score 5):

It was a bit of a design mistake in Winforms to make the BufferedGraphicsXxx classes public.  They are an implementation detail of double-buffering support in Winforms and they are not terribly resilient to using them wrong.

You are definitely using the BufferedGraphics you get back from Allocate() wrong.  You create buffers at a high rate, inside the game loop.  But you forget to dispose the buffer you used at the end of the loop.  This will consume device contexts (HDC's) at a high rate.  That doesn't go on forever, if your program doesn't otherwise get the garbage collector running then Windows pulls the plug and will not let you create a new device context.  The internal CreateCompatibleDC() call will fail and returns NULL.  The BufferedGraphicsContext class otherwise misses the code to check for this error and plows on with the NULL handle.  And starts painting to the desktop window instead of the form.

A fix will be to move the Allocate() call outside of the loop so you do it just once.  But now you'll have a new problem when the user changes the window size, the buffer is no longer the correct size.

The better mousetrap is to just not use the BufferedGraphics class but leave it up to Winforms to get it right.  There are several ways to get a gameloop in Winforms, but the simplest one is to just use the OnPaint() method to render the scene and immediately ask for another paint so it keeps getting called over and over again.  Similar to this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        RenderScene(e.Graphics);
        this.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Where RenderScene() should draw the game objects, using the passed Graphics instance.  Note that you no longer need to use Clear(), that was already done.

Comment: Isn't calling `Invalidate()` at the end of `OnPaint` going to use a lot of power when nothing moves, though?

Comment: Certainly, it burns 100% core, drawing the frames as fast as possible.  Just like his original game loop does.  The form otherwise stays completely responsive to input, painting is a low priority task.  If that's a problem then the simplest solution is a Timer whose Tick event handler calls Invalidate().  A 15 msec Interval gets 64 fps, 30 msec gets 32 fps, assuming it can keep up.